# BigQuery insert error, state: pending, status code 5

Tags: google-app-engine, google-bigquery

I am having bigquery insert error, which I can not find any solution to fix. I am doing stream insert using nodejs using google app engine. The error does not occur every time though. The log of the error is given as:

```html
{
 insertId:  "j5hzu8e36yg0"  
 logName:  "projects/xxxx-xxxx/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Fdata_access"  
 protoPayload: {
  @type:  "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog"   
  authenticationInfo: {
   principalEmail:  "xxxx-xxxx@appspot.gserviceaccount.com"    
  }
  authorizationInfo: [
   0: {
    granted:  true     
    permission:  "bigquery.jobs.create"     
    resource:  "projects/xxxx-xxxx"     
   }
  ]
  methodName:  "jobservice.getqueryresults"   
  requestMetadata: {
   callerIp:  "xx.xx.xx.xx"    
   callerSuppliedUserAgent:  "gcloud-dotnet/1.0.0-beta18 google-api-dotnet-client/1.35.1.0 (gzip),gzip(gfe)"    
  }
  resourceName:  "projects/xxxx-xxxx/queries/job_bc378dc9_240d_4caf_acfa_d54691ffe595"   
  serviceData: {
   @type:  "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.bigquery.logging.v1.AuditData"    
   jobGetQueryResultsRequest: {
   }
   jobGetQueryResultsResponse: {
    job: {
     jobConfiguration: {
     }
     jobName: {
     }
     jobStatistics: {
     }
     jobStatus: {
      error: {
      }
      state:  "PENDING"       
     }
    }
   }
  }
  serviceName:  "bigquery.googleapis.com"   
  status: {
   code:  5    
   message:  "Not found: Job xxxx-xxxx:job_bc378dc9_240d_4caf_acfa_d54691ffe595"    
  }
 }
 receiveTimestamp:  "2018-11-22T07:24:42.323436659Z"  
 resource: {
  labels: {
   project_id:  "xxxx-xxxx"    
  }
  type:  "bigquery_resource"   
 }
 severity:  "ERROR"  
 timestamp:  "2018-11-22T07:24:41.794Z"
```

Let me know if you need further information.

Comment: Can you share the code too?

Comment: bigquery
  .dataset('raw')
  .table(tbl)
  .insert(rows)
  .then(() => {
    console.log(`Inserted ${rows.length} rows`);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    if (err && err.name === 'PartialFailureError') {
      if (err.errors && err.errors.length > 0) {
        console.log('Insert errors:');
        err.errors.forEach(err => console.error(err));
      }
    } else {
      console.error('BQ INGEST ERROR CUST RAW:', err);
    }
  });
};

Comment: Audit log entry you provided corresponds to a failed request to retrieve job results (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/getQueryResults). And based on the user agent it was made using https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet. Can you attach a proper streaming insert response as defined at https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tabledata/insertAll?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like BigQuery is unable to find the geographic [location of the job](https://%20https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/locations#specifying_your_location).

Make sure to specify your region in the location property in the [jobReference](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#jobReference.location). Here is an [github example for nodejs](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-bigquery/blob/dba24fce864fe0641e254afe0f85499ea36ad421/src/dataset.ts) that you can consult.

UPDATE 
Check if the job that was not found was retried and successfully done. In streaming it needs a delay between requesting the job and try to retrieving it. So you can ignore such errors and give it a second try to get info.

Comment: Don't think it's a region or location property problem. I am using streaming insert which does not require location info. I followed the examples: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#bigquery-stream-data-nodejs

Comment: Can you test and see if you still have the error? This is to to eliminate/ validate this theory.

Comment: This does not help.

Comment: It looks like a nodejs client libraries issue. Can you [define the optional location parameter](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/bigquery/1.3.x/Table) when you create the table and see if you still get the error? You should also report this issue [here](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-bigquery/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=)